# 7-Zip Warning: "There are some data after the end of the payload data"

Tags: windows-10, compression, zip, 7-zip, archiving

I just got this error message while trying to extract a rar archive that is split in several parts using 7-Zip:

```
1   C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\FileName.part1.rar
    Warnings:
    There are some data after the end of the payload data
```

I already found several articles about this issue but all of them are a couple of years old. I've read that it used to be a bug in 7-Zip that this message was displayed. So that means the statement of the message was incorrect, I assume. However, these articles suggest to update 7-Zip to solve the problem. But I'm already using a version (7-Zip 21.03 beta (x64)) that is a lot more recent than the current version to the time these articles were written. So I would like to find some more recent information about this problem. Is it still a bug or is my archive really corrupt?

The rar archive I downloaded is split in several parts:

```
FileName.part1.rar
FileName.part.2.rar
FileName.part.3.rar
FileName.part.4.rar
FileName.part.5.rar
```

I found it a little strange that the parts are named in a different format ("part1.rar" vs "part.1.rar"). At first I had to rename all part to a format like "part1.rar" to extract the archive.

Nonetheless, I would like to know what that error message means? Is it a bug from 7-Zip or is the archive corrupt? Is it suspicious if there is more data "hidden" at the end of the rar file than the actual archive?

Comment: Note that you aren't including the possibility that someone simply chose to put some data after the end of the archive.

Comment: First question to ask: is the archive extracting OK? Is the data that is extracted correct and complete? If so, it's possible there's just some extra data after the usable files, possibly included by the packaging utility. Metadata isn't uncommon.

Comment: Yes, the extracted data is okey and works fine. Then I guess you're right, it might be some additional data by the packaging software.

Comment: And could you open this rar by clicking on it in Windows File Explorer? I got similar error on zip file which I first put into Git repository and then pull it on other host - then I cannot open it by double clicking in File Exprorer and when extracting with 7-Zip I got this message (though it extracted fine)

Comment: Yes, I could open it in 7-Zip.